# How to pass argument from django template to views on clicking list item from list?

Tags: javascript, python, html, django, web

In my template I have a list containing some items under headings of name and id and i want to add hyperlink to each of them item and when i click an item it takes it's id as argument to the function in views.py of django and run that function.

Currently my templates looks like:

```
<html>
<head>
<body>


<table border="1" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="5">

<td>ID</td>
<td>Name</td>

{% for i in data%}

<tr>
<td>{{i.ID}}</td>
<td>{{i.Name}}</td>
</tr>

{% endfor %}

</table>

</body>
</head></html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply do a href after your td. In your views you can do the function thing. You need to define a function which takes the id argument.

```html
<html>
<head>
<body>


<table border="1" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="5">

<td>ID</td>
<td>Name</td>

{% for i in data%}

<tr>
<td>{{i.ID}}</td>
<td> <a href="/yourpath/{{i.id}}"{{i.Name}}></td>
</tr>

{% endfor %}

</table>

</body>
</head></html>
```

```py
def your_function_name(request, YOUR_ID):

   # code
```

Also in your urls.py

```py
urlpatterns= [
    path('your_path/<your_id>/', views.your_function_name, name='your_name'),
]
```

Comment: but how the function will take id as argument and use that argument in function. It says function got unexpected argument

Comment: when you click the item in the table, it will go to your path. < > this is where you pass your argument to your path and also your function. after request it expects from you to give the argument to function. afterwards the rest is simple python.

Comment: i couldn't get it could you please edit your solution and make it more detailed please?

Comment: Did you try to do my solution as it is in the answer ?

Comment: yup and it says page not found